# Rigorously understanding chain rule for sum of functions

Tags: partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, chain-rule

In my quest to understand the Euler-Lagrange equation, I've realized I have to understand the chain rule first. So, here's the issue:

We have $g(\epsilon) = f(t) + \epsilon h(t)$. We have to compute $\frac{\partial F(g(\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon}$. This is supposed to be equal to $\frac{\partial F(f)}{\partial f}h(t)$ when $\epsilon = 0$. However, this does not make any sense to me. Doing the computations and using the chain rule, I get:
$$\frac{\partial F(g(0))}{\partial \epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{F(g(\epsilon)) - F(g(0))}{g(\epsilon) -g(0) } \frac{g(\epsilon) -g(0)}{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{F(f(t)+\epsilon h(t)) - F(f(t))}{\epsilon h(t) } h(t) $$
On an intuitive level I can understand it. I can think of $f(t)+\epsilon h(t)$ as $f+\Delta f$ since $h$ can be any arbitrary function, and that allows me to use the other definition of the derivative. However, I do not think this is a very rigorous way of doing it.

How can I show that $\frac{\partial F(g(0))}{\partial \epsilon} = \frac{\partial F(f)}{\partial f}h(t)$ using the definition of the derivative? Or, rather, a definition of the derivative..?

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht You could say it is both. We are using $g$ to examine what will happen when we change one function by small amounts (so, we are considering the entire curve). So, only $\epsilon$ matters for this purpose. However, both $t$ and $\epsilon$ are real numbers.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Well, you do that every time you use the chain rule: $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\frac{df(g)}{dg}\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$. The $\frac{df(g)}{dg}$ part of this equation is differentiating with respect to the function g (although, that is not technically what you are doing, but, in terms of computation, that is what you are doing). If this is unclear, look at the Wikipedia article on the chain rule. There are three proofs on the chain rule there. They should make what I am writing here clear.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Also, F is just another function. Instead of a number or a vector, the input is another function. Look into function composition if you have not encountered this before. In fact, you should do this before you try to understand differentiation with respect to a function.